# Importance Sampling in Off-policy n-step Sarsa

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

In Chapter 7.3 of *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction* by Sutton and Barto, the off-policy pseudocode has the following update equation for $Q$:

1. Compute importance sampling ratio:
   $$ \rho \leftarrow \prod^{\min(\tau+n-1, T-1)}_{i=\tau+1} \frac{\pi(A_i \mid S_i)}{b(A_i \mid S_i)} $$
2. Compute truncated return
   $$ G \leftarrow \sum^{\min(\tau+n, T)}_{i = \tau+1} \gamma^{i-\tau-1} R_i $$
3. Compute discounted estimate:

$$ \text{If } \tau+n < T, G \leftarrow G + \gamma^n Q(S_{\tau+n}, A_{\tau+n}) $$

4. Update $Q$

$$ Q(S_\tau, A_\tau) \leftarrow Q(S_\tau, A_\tau) + \alpha \rho [G - Q(S_\tau, A_\tau)] $$

($\tau$ is the time whose estimate is being updated, $t$ is current timestep, $n$ is $n$-step return, and $T$ is termination timestep)

I believe that the importance sampling ratio $\rho$ should only be multiplied to $G$ and not to $Q$, since $Q$ is for target policy $\pi$ and $G$ is from behavior policy $b$. In other words, this is how I see this equation:

$$ Q_\pi \leftarrow Q_\pi + \alpha \rho_{b \to \pi} [G_b - Q_\pi]$$

Am I correct in thinking that this is a typo, or did I miss something?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like someone else asked themselves the [same question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284394/three-doubts-about-off-policy-n-step-sarsa-algorithm). It makes sense for the ratio to be multiplied to G only, since it's only G that uses the behavior policy to sample the next n rewards.

Comment: Didn't see that! Thank you for the reference.